# Add rows for each day that lies in a period in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am working on a table 'booking' -
[image: BOOKING]

I want to add a column 'date_of_stay' to this table where date_of_stay will store each date in  the period that a booking_id will stay for as per the number of nights given by column 'nights'.
FOR eg-

```
booking_id    booking_date        nights    date_of_stay

5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Thu, 03 Nov 2016
5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Fri, 04 Nov 2016
5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Sat, 05 Nov 2016
5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Sun, 06 Nov 2016
5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Mon, 07 Nov 2016
5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Tue, 08 Nov 2016
5001        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       7        Wed, 09 Nov 2016
5002        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       2        Thu, 03 Nov 2016
5002        Thu, 03 Nov 2016       2        Fri, 04 Nov 2016
```

What can be the simplest way of viewing my table like this without altering it?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select booking_id, booking_date, nights, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select booking_id, booking_date, nights, 1 + n
      from cte
      where n < nights
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

According this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-generate-days-from-the-range-of-dates-in-MySQL) you can use next query:

```
select booking.*, date_of_stay
from (
  select adddate('2015-01-01', t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) date_of_stay from
    (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3
) v
join booking ON date_of_stay between 
    booking.booking_date and date_add(booking.booking_date, interval nights-1 day)
order by booking_id, date_of_stay
;
```

The above query works in MYSQL 5 & 8 as well. It is valid for all dates in interval:

```
select '2015-01-01' from_date, adddate('2015-01-01',9*1000 + 9*100 + 9*10 + 9) to_date;
+------------+------------+
|  from_date |    to_date |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-01-01 | 2042-05-18 |
+------------+------------+
```

Here query can be tested [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=3ae346e664eb10d2eee3170981dff872&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT booking_id, booking_date, nights, 0 nr, 
         STR_TO_DATE(booking_date, '%a, %d %b %Y') date_of_stay
  FROM booking
  UNION ALL
  SELECT booking_id, booking_date, nights, nr + 1,
         date_of_stay + interval 1 day
  FROM cte       
  WHERE nr < nights - 1       
)
SELECT c.booking_id, c.booking_date, c.nights, 
       DATE_FORMAT(c.date_of_stay, '%a, %d %b %Y') date_of_stay
FROM cte c
ORDER BY c.booking_id, c.date_of_stay
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b80678da685cd967083920a77fee524).
Results:

```
> booking_id | booking_date     | nights | date_of_stay    
> ---------: | :--------------- | -----: | :---------------
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Fri, 04 Nov 2016
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Sat, 05 Nov 2016
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Sun, 06 Nov 2016
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Mon, 07 Nov 2016
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Tue, 08 Nov 2016
>       5001 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      7 | Wed, 09 Nov 2016
>       5002 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      2 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016
>       5002 | Thu, 03 Nov 2016 |      2 | Fri, 04 Nov 2016
```